# php urlencode not working

Tags: php, urlencode

Here is the array I have

```
var_dump($arr);
// prints below array
[0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Lee Daniels' The Butler (2013)
        )
```

I want to remove the year along with braces and replace the spaces(" ") with underscore("_") and then urlencode it. Hence the desired output is

> Lee_Daniels%27_The_Butler

Here is my code:

```
$url = preg_replace('/\((\d){4}\)/', '', $arr[0]['title']);

$title = str_replace(" ","_", trim($url));
$title = urlencode($title); // tried with urlencode(addslashes($title));
echo $title; // prints Lee_Daniels'_The_Butler
```

I know echo urlencode('\'') gives "%27" and hence tried addslashes but to no avail.

**UPDATE:**
It works fine with

```
preg_replace('/\((\d){4}\)/', '', "Lee Daniels' The Butler (2013)");
```

But if you fetch the str directly as below:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/';
$main_content = file_get_html($url);

$table = $main_content->find('table', 0);
$tbody = $table->find('tbody', 0);

$trs = $tbody->find('tr');
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    $tds = $tr->find('td');
    $movies = "";

    $movies['title'] = trim($tds[2]->plaintext);

    $arr[] = $movies;
}

$url = preg_replace('/\((\d){4}\)/', '', $arr[0]['title']);

$title = str_replace(" ","_", trim($url));
$title = urlencode($title);
echo $title;
```

To replicate this please include simple html dom parser in the php.

Can somebody kindly point what I am missing?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://viper-7.com/DaEGUY

Comment: Is it working with addslashes or without? I am on Mac by the way and I hope that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave you?

Comment: That never loads. I've been trying to load it since the last 5 mins. Is that a short url?

Comment: Hmm looks like viper-7 is down again. I used exactly what you have above.

Comment: Thats weird. I've been hitting my head since the last 2 hours completely lost. I mean this is such a silly problem, but am not able to get it work.

Comment: I hope you're doing `preg_replace('/\((\d){4}\)/', '', "Lee Daniels' The Butler (2013)");`?

Comment: Since viper-7.com is down: http://codepad.org/R39UYhCJ

Comment: @Mike please check my comment on codepad

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code provided actually works as expected.

Comment: I really don't see any problem here. Unless you can produce a working example of what is going wrong, the question is rather useless. In the meantime I am voting to close this question. Feel free to edit it with an example that is reproducible causing this error.

Comment: @Mike Please look at the code snippet below **UPDATE:**. Include simple html dom from http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=218559. Before you include simple html dom please read this http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/79/#4a5c. I am sure you'll be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The fact is that the only way the code wouldn't work is if `$arr[0]['title']` doesn't contain what you think it contains. The rest of the code simply uses native PHP functions. Try doing `var_dump($arr[0]['title'])` and `var_dump($title);` and looking at the page's source code (not the outputted HTML).

Comment: `var_dump($arr[0]['title']);  // string(35) "Lee Daniels' The Butler (2013)"
var_dump($title);  // string(34) "Lee_Daniels%26%23x27%3B_The_Butler"`
This is from the source code.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running it in a loop somehow and double encoding it?

Comment: No I am not. Well I figured out the problem. If you look at the source of this page http://www.imdb.com/chart/ you'll see that the single quotes are actually hex codes which causes this problem. Is there a native php function to handle these chars?

Comment: You need [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Does not work
`$test = html_entity_decode($arr[0]['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
$test1 = trim(preg_replace('/\((\d){4}\)/', '', $test));
$test2 = str_replace(" ","_", $test1);
$test3 = urlencode(addslashes($test2));
var_dump($test3);  // prints "Lee_Daniels%5C%27_The_Butler"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/';
$main_content = file_get_html($url);

$table = $main_content->find('table', 0);
$tbody = $table->find('tbody', 0);

$trs = $tbody->find('tr');
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    $tds = $tr->find('td');
    $movies = "";

    $movies['title'] = trim($tds[2]->plaintext);

    $arr[] = $movies;
}

$title = html_entity_decode($arr[0]['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$title = trim(preg_replace('/\((\d){4}\)/', '', $title));
$title = str_replace(" ", "_", $title);
$title = urlencode($title);

echo $title;
```

Please note that screen scraping is against the Conditions of IMDB as mentioned [here](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions). This is just for learning purposes.